# Is a slightly changed compiler allowed?

Tags: discussion, code-golf

Some maybe not-intended-to-program languages may have some extra limitations. Is it allowed to change it to solve a problem? If so, how the length go?

p.s. marking this topic as duplicate of [this topic](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/13593/) generally seems to allow an 0-byte solution loophole, for it's sometimes hard to define "slightly" and that's why I choose to count the changing byte count

Comment: I'm pretty sure it will count as a separate language. Also, why specifically [meta-tag:code-golf]?

Comment: If you change the compiler, it's a new language.

Comment: Not necesarily an interpreter bug, as I can see. But definitely similar.

Comment: Also see https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6918/what-programming-languages-have-been-created-by-ppcg-users

Comment: By the way, whatever your language is, intended to be a programming language or not, as long as it can add two numbers and check a number's primality, it's considered a programming language here.

Comment: @user202729 If the modified language appears before the challenge, it is a valid language; but what if not?

Comment: The community [allows languages newer than challenge](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/12877/lets-allow-newer-languages-versions-for-older-challenges) now. As long as the language is linked somewhere so people can test it, it's fine.

Comment: @user202729 No if it's hard to say whether the new language is only for the challenge(or, though it usually lead to downvotes, it still valid?)